# Что значит (void**)&?

Tags: c++

Нашёл в интернете код:

```
BYTE* memory; 
memory=new BYTE[40000000];  
hbmp=CreateDIBSection(WndHDC,&bmi,DIB_RGB_COLORS,  (void**)&memory,NULL,0);
```

Что значит `(void**)&`? Насколько я понял, выражение `(void**)` приводит указатель memory к типу указатель на указатель (Так? Если да, то зачем этот тип вообще нужен? Зачем нужен указатель на указатель?!). А зачем тут & ?

Comment: `CreateDIBSection` запишет адрес `DIB'а` в память по адресу, который передается 4-м параметром, поэтому сюда нужно передать **адрес** указателя. Адрес получаем операцией `&`. А приводить приходится потому что memory является указателем на BYTE, а не на void.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Смотрим в интернете определение этой функции

```
HBITMAP CreateDIBSection(
  _In_   HDC hdc,
  _In_   const BITMAPINFO *pbmi,
  _In_   UINT iUsage,
  _Out_  VOID **ppvBits,
  _In_   HANDLE hSection,
  _In_   DWORD dwOffset
);
```

Нужный параметр имеет вид `VOID **ppvBits`. Это объяснят первую часть `(void**)` - это просто приведение типа.  То есть нужен указатель на указатель. memory - это просто указатель, поэтому к нему применяется оператор взятия адреса `&`.

`memory` имеет тип `BYTE*`.
`&memory` имеет тип `BYTE**`.

Answer (score 4):

(void **) означает приведение к типу указатель на указатель типа void :) Смотрим [прототип](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
HBITMAP CreateDIBSection(
  _In_   HDC hdc,
  _In_   const BITMAPINFO *pbmi,
  _In_   UINT iUsage,
  _Out_  VOID **ppvBits,
  _In_   HANDLE hSection,
  _In_   DWORD dwOffset
);
```

Comment: @klopp, да, а после воид зачем амперсанд то стоит?! и без него код не работает

Comment: Затем же, зачем и передаётся адрес переменной, с &. В этот указатель будет записано новое значение: "ppvBits [out]: A pointer to a variable that receives a pointer to the location of the DIB bit values"